Catastrophic movie about a dam I saw years ago
I'm looking for a catastophic movie I saw years ago, I'm not sure how many but definitely at least 5 or more. It was dubbed in italian and I don't know where it came from originally.
It revolved around a dam which was being built/completed above a small town (probably in the USA). The protagonist was the engineer/architect/whatever who originally designed the dam. He was fired by the director of the building company (I guess) and he had some family issues, mainly with his son who was involved in some way in dam construction. Drama ensues, at the end the dam collapses, the evil owner of the company dies in his villa and the family of the protagonist survives.
I can recall quite clearly two particular scenes which occur in the movie. 
In the first one, the protagonist argues with his son about the size of some materials used in the construction, with the son accusing the father of using materials with a quality lower than the one enforced by the law and the father telling him that he actually wanted an even higher quality than the law requirement (it probably was something about girders, with the ones used being 15 something, the law being 30 something and the father requiring 40 something).
In the second one (which has to be one of my favorite death scenes ever), the dam is starting to collapse and the pressure of the water is blowing up pipes all around the plant. At some point, the guardian (should I call him like this?) of the dam who was also a friend of the protagonist is in some tunnel and is suddenly hit by a bolt shot by a rupturing pipe. He starts bleeding profusely and after a touching speech he dies.
I hope it's enough, I don't think it was shown in cinemas, maybe it was directly done for the tv. 

Sounds like Killer Flood: The Day the Dam Broke from 2003.

When the dam in the town of Rutland starts to show signs of wear, David Powell, the architect who originally worked on the dam but was removed and who left town after he was black balled by Walker, the man who only cares about making a profit; returns. He insists that the dam be drained and inspected but Walker claims it would take too long and would be too costly. David goes to the dam and notices a few anomalies. He then tries to warn the deputy mayor who happens to be his estranged wife but out of anger she refuses to listen. Also David tries to reconnect with his son who resents his desertion.

The local engineer sacrifices himself at some point and is killed by a shooting bolt. Here's the promo:




That movie looks...terrible. :)
